Table direction in word RTL little box
I was wondering if it's possible to flip the little box next to table in word programmatically while keeping the data in the same cells?
Here is an example:
When I copy table from html:

and paste it in a word document, it looks like this:

The red arrow shows where I want that square to be. I know about table direction that flips it all, but I'm looking for a programmical solution (python or VBA) due to large amount of tables it takes just too much time changing tables direction manually.

The square is part of Word’s UI and cannot be moved.

Try
Sub TableGrabbersOnRight()
Dim t As Word.Table
For Each t in ActiveDocument.Tables
  t.TableDirection = wdTableDirectionRtl
Next
End Sub

And yes, it does reverse the column sequence but AFAIK does not affect text direction.
